# XML response from fetch

Tags: javascript, xml, react-native, fetch

I'm using `fetch` in a react-native app. I'm trying to read the response but when I use an `alert(response)` I get `[object Object]`. I've tried with other modules such as xml2js, react-native-html-parser', or xmldom.

```
fetch(
  /*
       REQUEST CONFIGURATION
  */
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response) // This is what returns [object Object]
  })
```

Comment: Here is `Response` documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response , try using `response.json()` or `response.text()`

Comment: I did and I received the same result

Comment: If you just want to see the contents you should use `console.log(response)` and use the debugger to look at the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the response like this:

```
.then(response => {
      response.text().then(text => {
        // handle response content
        })
      })
```

Answer (score 8):

Reading the response body is an asynchronous operation, you need to wait for the promise to complete first:

```
fetch(config)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(bodyText => {
    // now you have the response body you can parse
  });
```

On another note, `alert` is a very blunt tool for debugging (I didn't even know it existed in React Native!). Try `console.log` in the "Debug JS Remotely" mode to get more information about the things you want to log.